# What should I do if "sudo /usr/share/bcc/tools/execsnoop" fails after build BCC from source?

Tags: python, c++, linux, ebpf, bcc-bpf

After building BCC from source and running the test "sudo /usr/share/bcc/tools/execsnoop", I got the following output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/bcc/tools/execsnoop", line 21, in 
from bcc import BPF
ImportError: No module named bcc

What does this mean and what can be done to remedy it?

After installing the dependencies, these are the steps that I followed:

```
git clone https://github.com/iovisor/bcc.git
mkdir bcc/build; cd bcc/build
# python2 can be substituted here, depending on your environment
cmake -DPYTHON_CMD=python3 ..
make && sudo make install

sudo /usr/share/bcc/tools/execsnoop #Test
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: My guess would be that you've installed it with one version of python but its trying to run with another

Comment: @Barmar This is a programming question. I'm building a library. What I'm essentially asking is why didn't the build process yield the correct result?

Comment: @AlanBirtles The build instructions told me to use "cmake -DPYTHON_CMD=python3 ..". Wouldn't this make it use Python 3?

Comment: Every time I've had this issue with bcc it was as @AlanBirtles pointed out: a problem of Python version. Did you try `sudo python3 /usr/share/bcc/tools/execsnoop`?

Comment: @pchaigno Yes this worked! Now it's telling me that I'm missing module headers.

Comment: presumably `/usr/share/bcc/tools/execsnoop` starts with `#!/bin/python`(or similar), change it to `#!/bin/python3`

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's correct! After I made that change, I no longer have to put python3 before the command.

Answer (score 3):

this is caused due to python2 is set as default python.

```
$ ls -l `which python`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar  4  2019 /usr/bin/python -> python2
```

there is one way to change all occurrences of

`#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python3`

or

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

or

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 100
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.7 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode
```

which will change python to alternatives python

```
$ ls -l `which python`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Nov 29 20:21 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```